# How to manually delete a subscription in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to delete a subscription using the SSRS Manager portal.  I get the following error when trying to delete the subscription:

There are two or more jobs named '12FC1298-3060-4CC9-B406-4A612FFDB620'. Specify @job_id instead of @job_name to uniquely identify the job.

I get the same error if I try to delete the entire report via the Report Manager portal.

How can I clean up this issue manually ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the database server that hosts the ReportingServices Database.

In the SQL Server Agent of that server, see if you can locate the job named '12FC1298-3060-4CC9-B406-4A612FFDB620'. If it is duplicated, delete one of the duplicates, then try to delete the subscription again via the SSRS Manager Portal.

If you do not see any duplicate jobs in the SQL Server Agent, have a look at the Subscriptions and Schedules-tables in the ReportingServices database, to see if you can figure out what's going on (these tables relate a Reporting Services Subscription to an SQL Server Agent job).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the single record I found and got an error message that said there was a duplicate, etc. However when I again selected from the subscriptions table using that ID, there were no records. So apparently both were deleted. I was then able to fix the schedule in the Manage option of the report in the SSRS folder. It seems to be a glitch because it deleted SOMETHING, but my subscription was still there in SSRS, the error just went away. No idea HOW this worked, but it did.